# Defining points with unequal intervals in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have the following for loop in c:

```
for (j=0; j<=NOUT; j++)
    {
            t[j] = -1.4 + 2.8*(double)j/100; 
    }
```

which creates a hundred points equally spaced between -1.4 and 2.8.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a loop which concentrates the number of points at a certain position, for example at 1 (or any given value between -1.4 and 2.8).

So the distance `t[j-1] - t[j]` gets smaller as `t[j]` approaches 1 and gets bigger as `t[j]` heads away from 1. Thus there is a higher concentration of points near `t[j]=1` for a given neighbourhood.

I not even too sure how one might attempt this task and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can, think of what you wrote as a simple coordinate transformation, or if you prefer, a function. Obviously it doesn't have to be linear, you want something where the derivative is not constant, if you wish to end up with varying densities of points at different places. The smaller the derivative, the higher the density will be.

Comment: Once you've described what you want mathematically the programming will be easy. Your best bet might be to pick a probability distribution e.g. [from here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/common-probability-distributions-the-data-scientists-crib-sheet/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) if they suit what you want?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a function which goes to 1 in an asymptotic way, something like `f(x)=1+1/x`.

Comment: Ah right, that would make it much easier. Thanks so much for the help.